# Python Unexpected character

Tags: python, syntax-error

Hey I'm getting this unexpected character after line error for this if statement

```
if (StartSquare % 10 != 0 and StartSquare % 10 != 9 and
      StartSquare \ 10 != 0 and StartSquare \ 10 != 9 and
      FinishSquare % 10 != 0 and FinishSquare % 10 != 9 and
      FinishSquare \ 10 != 0 and FinishSquare \ 10 != 9):
    ValidMove = True
```

Comment: what are you trying to compute with '\' ?

Comment: so if you enter two co-ords e.g 24, % gets 4 and \ gets 2

Comment: I dont think there is any operator like '\'. For division its '/'

Comment: Ahh Thanks, wasn't thinking straight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\` is an escape character, it tells Python that the *next* character may need to be ignored. In Python code, outside string literals, it is used to create logical line continuations:

```
foo = 'This is a longer string ' \
      'wrapped across more than one line'
```

Using it in the middle of a line has no real meaning; it is then ignored. To Python, your code looks like this:

```
if (StartSquare % 10 != 0 and StartSquare % 10 != 9 and
      StartSquare 10 != 0 and StartSquare 10 != 9 and
      FinishSquare % 10 != 0 and FinishSquare % 10 != 9 and
      FinishSquare 10 != 0 and FinishSquare 10 != 9):
```

which is not valid syntax; the `10` after `StartSquare` is unexpected.

If you wanted to use *division* then use a forward slash; `/`.

Since you are probably handling integers here, you'd really would use *floor division*: `//`. In Python 2 `/` does floor division when both operands are integers, but if `StartSquare` or `FinishSquare` was a float you'd get regular division instead, while `//` explicitly sticks to floor division even in that case.

Your expression is rather hard to 'grok'; perhaps you could test for specific numbers instead:

```
if StartSquare not in (0, 9, 90, 99) and FinishSquare not in (0, 9, 90, 99):
```

Comment: And if you want integer division use `//`.

Comment: is there any difference in using `/` and `//` while using Python2.x when both the operands are already integers?

Comment: @anmol_uppal: no, both will result in floor division in that case.

Comment: I recommend always to use `//`, because it is more portable.